WinApi не строится область отсечения для текста
Пытаюсь построить область отсечения для теста
BeginPath(hdc);
TextOut(hdc, 150, 100, text, lstrlen(text));
//Ellipse(hdc, 100, 100, 200, 200);
EndPath(hdc);
SelectClipPath(hdc, RGN_AND);

Теперь если попробовать получить эту область и рисовать в ней,
RECT rect;
GetClipBox(hdc, &rect);

то ничего не выйдет, этой области просто нет, но если отрисовать эллипс, то все нормально область есть и все работает. Как все-таки заставить работать область отсечения с текстом?

Нашел ответ: надо с помощью SelectClipRgn построить еще один регион вокруг текста, а потом сделать отсечение с параметром RGN_DIFF.
